# Crop one inch of PDF file

Tags: c#, pdf, crop

I need to resize a single page PDF from 8X11 inch to 8X9 inch (or any size), without resizing the content at all.

How can I do this in C# ?

Thanks

Comment: Yes. It is possible. Which pdf library do you want to use?

Comment: Simply a free one that does not display a demo version message.

Comment: *"a free one"* - which flavor of free? Is AGPL ok?

Comment: Any library that I can get from NuGet.

Comment: Where shall those 2" be cut off? At the top? The bottom? Half top, half bottom?

Comment: I want to ba able to cut the right part of the PDF to have a PDF of 88mm of width, keeping the same height. Forget about the 8x9 inch, it was just an example.

Comment: Is there a simple solution ?

Comment: Yes there is. But most likely I won't be in office this week anymore to write a proper answer. If nobody had answered then, I'll create an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be possible using any decent general purpose PDF library.

For example, to crop 1 inch from the right using iText 7:

```
using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(SOURCE_PDF))
using (PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(TARGET_PDF))
using (PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument(reader, writer))
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= document.GetNumberOfPages(); i++)
    {
        PdfPage page = document.GetPage(i);
        Rectangle cropBox = page.GetCropBox();
        cropBox.SetWidth(cropBox.GetWidth() - 72);
        page.SetCropBox(cropBox);
    }
}
```

If, as you mention in a comment, you actually want to *cut the right part of the PDF to have a PDF of 88mm of width, keeping the same height*, replace

```
        cropBox.SetWidth(cropBox.GetWidth() - 72);
```

by

```
        cropBox.SetWidth(88f * 72f / 25.4f);
```

The crop box dimensions are given in default user space units which in turn default to 1⁄72 inch. Thus, to set a dimension given in mm one has to multiply that number by (72/25.4) first.

---

Two remarks:

- Actually the *default user space unit* may differ if the page **UserUnit** property is set which is specified as

  > a positive number that shall give the size of default user space units, in multiples of 1⁄72 inch. The range of supported values shall be implementation-dependent.
  >
  > Default value: 1.0 (user space unit is 1⁄72 inch).

  *(ISO 32000-1, Table 30 – Entries in a page object)*

  This property is seldom used, though, in particular because of the "The range of supported values shall be implementation-dependent" bit, so I ignored it above.
- If you don't want to *crop* but instead to *enlarge* the page area, you'll probably not only need to enlarge the **CropBox** but also the **MediaBox**.

  > The crop, bleed, trim, and art boxes shall not ordinarily extend beyond the boundaries of the media box. If they do, they are effectively reduced to their intersection with the media box.

  *(ISO 32000-1, section 14.11.2.1 Page Boundaries / General)*

  `PdfPage` has analogous methods `GetMediaBox` and `SetMediaBox` that can be used for enlarging the **MediaBox**.

Comment: The only problem is that I now need to zoom the PDF by 500 % to have a comparable size as the previous content. Is there a solution ?

Comment: Can you share an example PDF to reproduce that? It sounds weird.

Comment: Forget about it, the problem comes from my original PDF.